# Outlook Web Add in deployment fails when multi factor authorization is set to true

Tags: outlook, office-js, manifest, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have been recently trying to create a new web add in for microsoft outlook. I am completely new to this. I have followed the documentation from microsoft and created a new simple web add in for outlook. Since my company allows access to outlook only via multi factor authorization, I set this property to true in the property window. When I run the add in via visual studio, the add in works. But when I made some changes to the manifest file (In the VersionOverrides xml tag, I place the add in in a new custom tab instead of default tab), it displays me a dialog box asking me to pick an account (microsoft account). When I pick my microsoft account, a new window appears saying that there were deployment errors. I can share my manifest file if it helps.

[manifest xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVxYG.png)

I tried running the project with multi factor authorization to false. It does not give me any deployment errors. But as I mentioned, my company mandates multi factor authorization, so this property has to be set to true. And this results in deploymemt error.

Comment: What errors do you get? Could you be more specific?

Comment: I tried starting the project from Visual studio. It says build succeeded but deployment failed. The error list is empty.

Comment: I understood that from your post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you do any changes in the manifest file I'd suggest clearing the Office cache. Here is what MS states for such scenarious:

> To remove an add-in that you've previously sideloaded on Windows, Mac, or iOS, you need to clear the Office cache on your computer.

> Additionally, if you make changes to your add-in's manifest (for example, update file names of icons or text of add-in commands), you should clear the Office cache and then re-sideload the add-in using an updated manifest. Doing so allows Office to render the add-in as it's described by the updated manifest.

Read more about that in the [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) article.

Also, you may want to validate your add-in's manifest file to ensure that it's correct and complete. Validation can also identify issues that are causing the error "Your add-in manifest is not valid" when you attempt to sideload your add-in. The [Validate an Office Add-in's manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest) article describes multiple ways to validate the manifest file.

Comment: Maybe I did not describe my problem clearly. When I pack my add in button in the default tab, it works. But when I pack it in a new custom tab, then it says it cannot be deployed (Visual studio does not describe why). If you want, I can send both versions of the manifest file (default tab and custom tab)

Comment: I understood that from your post. Try to clear the cache and validate the manifest.

Comment: I cleared the cache. When I validate my xml file, I get two errors (related to icons). But the errors are same for both versions of manifest file (default tab and custom tab). Only thing is that custom tab does not run while default tab runs

Comment: Do you have any problems with a newly created add-in with a custom tab?